# Reusing class names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, global

Is it in someway possible to reuse a class name that is defined in the Global objects list found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)? (Like Number, String)

Lets say that I want to have my own String class. I can define it, and use it like this:

String.js

```
export default class String {
}
```

App.js

```
import String from './String'

let string = new String();
```

This actually works, but then

- PHPStorm tells me: yeah you used a primitive object wrapper (thinking it's 
  the global object String).
- Then ESLint tells me: Disallow Primitive Wrapper Instances (no-new-wrappers)
- And lastly SonarQube tells me: The use of wrapper objects for primitive types is gratuitous, confusing and dangerous. Simple literals should be used instead.

So yeah is there a way to encapsulate my class so it doesn't get confused with the global String class?

Comment: Doing this is extremely bad practice. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: [This](http://e.lvme.me/oozm79d.jpg) sums up my reaction.

Comment: Because the object I'm trying to blueprint with my class is an actual string. Like the cloth. I've looked for synonyms, but there simply are none.

Comment: To be honest, this would not be a problem in any other language because of namespaces or packages. And therefore I don't see it as bad practice, but as a shortcoming of the language itself.

Comment: I don't think `String.js` actually defines the `String` class globally like this, which may or may not be the problem. Then again, if this is a naming issue, this is probably not the way you want to solve it.

Comment: I don't quite see the point. Since you're explicitly importing your class, why not just call it `MyString`? If your intention is to add methods to the existing `String` class, (carefully) add them to `String.prototype`.

Comment: @LarsW Indeed, it doesn't. The problem is that String is already a global class. See the link I've posted.

Comment: @robertklep, I'm not making a string (text), I'm making a class that represents strings of instruments. There simply is no synonym, and MyString is a concession I would not like to give into that easily. Like I said, I can do this in any mature language, is there a way in JavaScript?

Comment: @DavidMaes I don't see the problem. Although everyone is telling you that it's not a good idea, your code still runs, doesn't it? So it's perfectly possible in JS (in fact, I can't even get ESLint to complain about it).

Comment: @robertklep I don't think it's a bad idea to name a class by what it should be named. On top of that nobody told me why it is bad practice. Because I'm shadowing a class that I'm not using in the encapsulated class that I'm working in? I don't see how this is bad practice at all. Like I said, in a language with namespaces/packages, this would not be considered bad practice at all.

Comment: @DavidMaes it's bad practise because it makes code harder to understand for others. If that is not of your concern, you can create classes called `String` and hopefully never run into the situation where you also need to use the global constructor (although you can always set up something like `instruments.String` instead). It's not very helpful to keep referring to other languages when clearly it _is_ possible what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155690/discussion-between-david-maes-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import './String'
```

Function and class definitions are local to the module. You're importing the file, but not using anything from it.

That's why this:

```
let string = new String();
```

will use the global String—there is no `String` definition in the module scope.

Make sure you name the imports you need:

```
import String from './String'
```

Incidentally, this is one of multiple reasons why it is better practice to give your String class a unique name, like `PhysicsString` or `StringMaterial` or `Thread`. That way if you forget to import it somewhere, you won't accidentally be using the global definition.

Comment: Ah That was actually my mistake, I actually already do what you said. I've editted the question. Same problem though. Like I said, the JS does the trick. But my code conventions don't see that I'm using my own class instead.

Comment: @DavidMaes Most likely the linters go by the name of the constructor only, and don't actually look it up in the scope. I would however expect some kind of "`import is shadowing global variable" warning as well.

Comment: @Bergi I know that all my classes are encapsulated very clearly, and therefore shadowing is something that can't be done "by accident". This is not bad practice if the class you're using obviously imports a new definition for String.

Comment: Oohh, I see, it's just the linters. Sorry, I missed that. For eslint you could disable the rule, heh, but it's probably easier to rename the class…

Comment: @Renée, I would if there were any synonyms that didn't make my code less legible. Finding meaningful (and searchable) names is much more important to me. I could turn off these linter checks, but I feel like actually using new String('hello world') IS bad practice.

Comment: Then I'm afraid the only remaining solution that I can think of is to patch the linters with scope analysis ://

Comment: @Renée Thanks, at least I have my answer, I wish JavaScript was a bit much mature.

Comment: @DavidMaes You can easily namespace identifiers in Javascript. Just add your own ID string in front of global identifiers. The Java naming way: `com-mydomain-String` but with dashes for dots so that you don't have to use `obj["propname"]` style access, just to give an example. I don't see the problem :-) Anyway, you already got your answer a long time ago. All this commenting and chatting too does not lead to any different result, but hey, to each their own I guess.

Comment: `I wish JavaScript was a bit much mature`  This isn't Javascript complaining, it's the Linter.  I use C# / C++ / Pascal and a few other languages, I'd say Javascript is pretty mature now.  In fact so mature I hate going back to the other ones. :)